# Missing items in android studio palette

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm very new to Android SDK and am currently trying to follow YouTube tutorials. I have one problem, I am missing items such as Large Text, Medium Text, Small Text - from the palette. How would I go about adding these items into the pallet?

First image is my palette

[image]

Second image is a YouTubers palette:

[image]

Comment: It's better to use xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a option in newer versions of Android Studio. Just pick `textView` and then you can set desired text size in panel in the right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I understand the difference in versions now. Easy mistake to make as I'm coming from a Visual Studio background. And in Visual Studio the controls are named Large text, Small Text, etc